# how to change the value of variable after calling the function using tablesasjson?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm

why the variable cannot be changed after calling the function?

this is my code:

```
const tabletojson = require('tabletojson');

var email ;

tabletojson.convertUrl(

    'https://myurl
    ,
    { stripHtmlFromCells: true },
    function(tablesAsJson) {


  email = tablesAsJson[2][7][1];
var result2 = tablesAsJson;
        console.log(result2);
        var Firstname;
        var lastname;
        Firstname = tablesAsJson[0][1][1]
        lastname = tablesAsJson[0][0][1]

        console.log("Hello Sir: "+Firstname + "  " +lastname + ".  your email is : " + email)

        console.log(email)// this prints the correct answer
    }
  );
```

> while trying to print email in out scope of the function its
>   returning a blank text with 
>   console.log("the email is " + email);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use this code as exported function from a module, you need something like this:

> test-module.js:

```
'use strict';

const tabletojson = require('tabletojson');

async function getTableAsArray(url) {
  try {
    return await tabletojson.convertUrl(url);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  getTableAsArray,
};
```

> test.js:

```
'use strict';

const testModule = require('./test-module.js');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const array = await testModule.getTableAsArray(
      'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes'
    );
    console.log(array[1][0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Method convertUrl is asynchronous and you cant use like *await* in the top-level code as you want.

Comment: any idea how to do it? with your method i am getting ' await is only valid in async function'

Comment: I think you can read value only in callback or in Promise(...).then(...)